# Got error while using pandas to make a table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use pandas datafaram to make a table such that x should be first column of my table,y should be second and z should be third. But I am getting ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (5, 5). This error is due to the shape but I don't know how can I fix that. Can someone help how to fix it.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]
z = [100,200,300,400,500]

pandas.DataFrame(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
pandas.DataFrame([x,y,z]).T
```

Without the `.T`, you are making `x`, `y`, `z` each a column. Then you transpose it to get the format you want.